# Which fonts satisfy the following attributes?

Tags: beamer, fonts

I will be giving a talk in Mathematics. Please suggest some fonts so that the beamer presentation has the following qualities:

- clarity
- viewing at large distances
- math is rendered easily
- easy on the eye
- aesthetics (? maybe too subjective)

Comment: This is *very* subjective. I think the default looks pretty (good).

Comment: @Werner I am looking for some other fonts.

Comment: Then consider the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/)...

Comment: I think this would give you some ideas http://faq.ktug.org/wiki/uploads/MathFonts.pdf and with that I'll vote for opinion based because we can't deal with choice questions due to our format.

Comment: I use Latin Modern. I don't know if that differs much from the default: `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{textcomp,lmodern}\usepackage[small,T1}{eulervm}`. (Not sure if I'm really using the `eulervm` - maybe I use a symbol or something.)